# Centroidal Coordinates of the Remaining Circle

Tags: geometry

I was looking for the coordinates of the centroid of the figure below:

[image: (figure here)]

**My work**

To get the coordinates of centroid of the figure above, I need to use the formula 
$$A r = A_1r_1 + A_2r_2 + A_3r_3 +A_4r_4 +....A_n r_n$$
where:
$A = $ area of the whole figure

$r = $ distance of the centroid from the $x$-axis

$A_1 = $ area of one part of the figure

$r_1 = $ distance of its particular centroid from the $x$-axis

The formula that is applicable to the figure above would be:
$$A r = A_1r_1 + A_2r_2 + A_3r_3 +A_4r_4$$
Redrawing the figure to make things clearer:

[image: (figure here)]

Now getting the A, A$_1$, A$_2$, A$_3$, A$_4$:

For A:
$$A = \pi R^2  \pi r^2= \pi (5 \space cm)^2 - \pi (2.5 \space cm)^2= 25\pi \space cm^2 - 6.25\pi \space cm^2= 18.75\pi \space cm^2$$

For A$_1$:
$$A_1 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2 - \frac{6.25}{2}\pi\space cm^2=3.125\pi \space cm^2$$
For A$_4$:
$$A_4 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2 - \frac{6.25}{2}\pi\space cm^2= 3.125\pi \space cm^2$$
For A$_2$:
$$A_2 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2$$
For A$_3$:
$$A_3 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2$$
Now getting the r, r$_1$, r$_2$, r$_3$, r$_4$:

For r: we can get it after I got r$_1$, r$_2$, r$_3$, r$_4$

For r$_1$: I don't know. The figure looks weird

For r$_2$. The centroid coordinates of a quarter circle is:
$$\bar x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r\qquad \bar y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$

Then the centroid coordinates would be:
$$\bar x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r= \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)= 2.1 \space cm$$
$$\bar y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r= \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)= 2.1 \space cm$$

For r$_3$:
The centroid coordinates of a quarter circle is:
$$\bar x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r\quad \bar y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$

Then the centroid coordinates would be:
$$\bar x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r= \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)= 2.1 \space cm$$
$$\bar y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r= \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)= 2.1 \space cm= -2.1 \space cm$$

For r$_4$: I don't know. The figure looks weird to me.

I was able to get A, A$_1$, A$_2$, A$_3$, A$_4$, r$_2$, and r$_3$. I wans't able to get r, r$_1$, and r$_4$ due to its weird shape.

How to get the centroid coordinates of the figure above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your evaluation is not correct. By symmetry $\bar{y}$ should be $0$!

As regards $\bar{x}$, the computation is easier if you consider the given area as a "difference" of the two disks: $D_1$ (the bigger one) and $D_2$ (the smaller one). You might also think $D_1$ with density $1$ and $D_2$ with density $-1$.  Looking at your formula
$$|D_1|x_1=|R|\bar{x}+|D_2|x_2.$$
where $R$ is the region with the hole. Then $|R|=|D_1|-|D_2|$ and
$$\bar{x}=\frac{|D_1|x_1-|D_2|x_2}{|D_1|-|D_2|}=\frac{\pi 5^2\cdot 5-\pi(5/2)^2(5+5/2)}{\pi 5^2-\pi(5/2)^2}=\frac{25}{6}.$$

Comment: Another way to put it is, let $A_0$ be the area of the figure in the question, and $r_0$ the radius to its centroid, then (using formulas you already know) $D_1 = D_2 + A_0$ and $D_1r_1 = D_2r_2 + A_0r_0.$ Solve for $A_0$ and $r_0$ and you end up evaluating the formulas in this answer.

Comment: Hmmm....I didn't think that using "density" can be used to get the centroid of the figure above.....I will delve into it to understand your solution......

Comment: @PalautotKa For geometric centroid uniform density is assumed... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: What do we call to the shape of the figure described by area A$_1$ ? I'm going to peek at its formula to get ts centroid...

Comment: @PalautotKa Looking at your formula $|D_1|x_1=|R|\bar{x}+|D_2|x_2.$  where $R$ is the region with the hole. Then find $\bar{x}$.

Comment: My answer is pretty close to yours.....$(4.18, 0)$ vs $(4.16, 0)$

Answer (score 0):

To get the coordinates of centroid of the figure above, we need to use the formula

$$A \bar x = A_1x_1 + A_2x_2 + A_3x_3 +A_4x_4 +....A_n x_n$$ $$A \bar y = A_1y_1 + A_2y_2 + A_3y_3 +A_4y_4 +....A_n y_n$$

where:

$A = $ area of the whole figure

$x = $ distance of the centroid from the $x$-axis

$A_1 = $ area of one part of the figure

$x_1 = $ distance of its particular centroid from the $x$-axis

.

.

.

.

.

.

$y = $ distance of the centroid from the $y$-axis

$A_1 = $ area of one part of the figure

$y_1 = $ distance of its particular centroid from the $y$-axis

The formula that is applicable to the figure above (See first drawing) would be:

$$A \bar x = A_1x_1 + A_2x_2 + A_3x_3 +A_4x_4 $$ $$A \bar y = A_1y_1 + A_2y_2 + A_3y_3 +A_4y_4 $$

Redrawing the figure to make things clearer:

(See 2nd Drawing)

Now getting the A, A$_1$, A$_2$, A$_3$, A$_4$:

For A:

$$A = \pi R^2  \pi r^2$$ $$A = \pi (5 \space cm)^2 - \pi (2.5 \space cm)^2$$ $$A = 25\pi \space cm^2 - 6.25\pi \space cm^2$$ $$A = 18.75\pi \space cm^2$$

For A$_1$:

$$A_1 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2 - \frac{6.25}{2}\pi\space cm^2$$ $$A_1 = 3.125\pi \space cm^2$$

For A$_4$:

$$A_4 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2 - \frac{6.25}{2}\pi\space cm^2$$ $$A_4 = 3.125\pi \space cm^2$$

For A$_2$:

$$A_2 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2$$

For A$_3$:

$$A_3 = \frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2$$

Now getting the x, x$_1$, x$_2$, x$_3$, x$_4$:

For x:

We can get it after I got x$_1$, x$_2$, x$_3$, x$_4$

For x$_1$:

[image: <img src="/sites/default/files/users/8eightI%27sD/a_1_circle.png" width="359" height="223" alt="a_1_circle.png" />]

Then the centroidal coordinates of A$_1$ is:

$$ x_1 = 0.3488 r$$ $$ x_1 = (0.3488) (5 \space cm)$$ $$ x_1 = 1.744 \space cm$$

The real value of $ x_1$ is:

$$\bar x_1 = 5 + 1.744 \space cm = 6.744 \space cm$$

For x$_2$

The centroidal coordinates of a quarter circle is:

[image: <img src="/sites/default/files/users/8eightI%27sD/circle_5.png" width="525" height="96" alt="circle_5.png" />]

$$\bar x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$ $$\bar y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$

Then the centroidal coordinates of A$_2$

[image: <img src="/sites/default/files/users/8eightI%27sD/circle3.png" width="327" height="203" alt="circle3.png" />]

$$ x_2 = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$ $$ x_2 = \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)$$ $$ x_2 = 2.1 \space cm$$

The real value of $x_2$ is:

$$x_3 = 5-2.1 \space cm = 2.9 \space cm$$

For x$_3$:

The centroidal coordinates of a quarter circle is:

[image]

$$ x = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$ $$ y = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$

Then the centroidal coordinates of A$_3$

[image: <img src="/sites/default/files/users/8eightI%27sD/circle4.png" width="314" height="218" alt="circle4.png" />]

$$ x_3 = \frac{4}{3\pi} r$$ $$ x_3 = \frac{4}{3\pi} (5 \space cm)$$ $$ x_3 = 2.1 \space cm$$

The real value of $x_3$ is:

$$x_3 = 5-2.1 \space cm = 2.9 \space cm$$

For x$_4$:

[image: <img src="/sites/default/files/users/8eightI%27sD/circle2.png" width="315" height="273" alt="circle2.png" />]

Then the centroidal coordinates of A$_4$ is:

$$ x_4 = 0.3488 r$$ $$ x_4 = (0.3488) (5 \space cm)$$ $$ x_4 = 1.744 \space cm$$

The real value of $ x_4$ is:

$$ x_4 = 5 + 1.744 \space cm = 6.74 \space cm $$

We can now get the $\bar x$:

$$A \bar x = A_1x_1 + A_2x_2 + A_3x_3 +A_4x_4 $$ $$(18.75\pi \space cm^2) \bar x = (3.125\pi \space cm^2)(6.744 \space cm) + (\frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2)(2.9 \space cm) + (\frac{25}{4}\pi \space cm^2)(2.9 \space cm) + (3.125\pi \space cm^2)(6.744 \space cm) $$ $$\bar x = 4.18 \space cm$$

To get the $\bar y$, notice that the figure is symmetrical, so the $\bar y$ centroidal coordinate would be $0$

Therefore, the centroid $C(\bar x, \bar y)$ of the figure above would be $C(\bar x, \bar y) = C(4.18, 0)$

Alternate solutions are encouraged:-)